# How can I ensure consistent axis lengths between plots with discrete variables in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been trying to standardise multiple bar plots so that the bars are all identical in width regardless of the number of bars. Note that this is over multiple distinct plots - faceting is not an option. It's easy enough to scale the plot area so that, for instance, a plot with 6 bars is 1.5* the width of a plot with 4 bars. This would work perfectly, except that each plot has an expanded x axis by default, which I would like to keep.

"The defaults are to expand the scale by 5% on each side for continuous variables, and by 0.6 units on each side for discrete variables."
https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_discrete.html

My problem is that I can't for the life of me work out what '0.6 units' actually *means*. I've manually measured the distance between the bars and the y axis in various design tools and gotten inconsistent answers, so I can't factor '0.6 units' into my calculations when working out what size the panel windows should be. Additionally I can't find any answers on how many 'units' long a discrete x axis is - I assumed at first it would be 1 unit per category but that doesn't fit with the visuals at all. I've included an image that hopefully shows what I mean - [the two graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wrHw.jpg)

In this image, the top graph has a plot area exactly 1.5* that of the bottom graph. Seeing as it has 6 bars compared with 4, that would mean each bar is the same width, except that that extra space between the axis and the first bar messes this up. Setting `expand = expansion(add = c(0, 0))` clears this up but results in not-so-pretty graphs. What I'd like is for the bars to be identical in width between the two plots, accounting for this extra space. I'm specifically looking for a general solution that I can use for future plots, not for the individual solution for this sample. As such, what I'd really like to know is how many 'units' long are these two x axes? Many thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using expansion for the axis, I would probably use the fact that categorical variables are actually plotted on the positive integers on Cartesian co-ordinates. This means that, provided you know the maximum number of columns you are going to use in your plots, you can set this as the range in `coord_cartesian`. There is a little arithmetic involved to keep the bars centred, but it should give consistent results.

We start with some reproducible data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(group = letters[1:6], value = 100 * runif(6))
```

Now we set the value for the maximum number of bars we will need:

```r
MAX_BARS <- 6
```

And the only thing "funny" about the plot code is the calculation of the x axis limits in `coord_cartesian`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(group, value)) + 
  geom_col() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1 -(MAX_BARS - length(unique(df$group)))/2,
                           MAX_BARS - (MAX_BARS - length(unique(df$group)))/2))
```

[image]

Now let us remove one factor level and run the exact same plot code:

```r
df <- df[-1,]

ggplot(df, aes(group, value)) + 
  geom_col() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1 -(MAX_BARS - length(unique(df$group)))/2,
                           MAX_BARS - (MAX_BARS - length(unique(df$group)))/2))
```

[image]

And again:

```r
df <- df[-1,]

ggplot(df, aes(group, value)) + 
  geom_col() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1 -(MAX_BARS - length(unique(df$group)))/2,
                           MAX_BARS - (MAX_BARS - length(unique(df$group)))/2))
```

[image]

And again:

```r
df <- df[-1,]

ggplot(df, aes(group, value)) + 
  geom_col() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1 -(MAX_BARS - length(unique(df$group)))/2,
                           MAX_BARS - (MAX_BARS - length(unique(df$group)))/2))
```

[image]

You will see the bars remain constant width and centralized, yet the panel size remains fixed.

<sup>Created on 2021-11-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Many thanks for getting back to me. Unless I'm missing something, wouldn't that result in a panel that's much larger than the bars? I'm not looking to standardise the panel sizes, just to have bars that are the same width between plots. For instance, one of my plots has >20 bars, whereas the smallest has only 4. The latter plot should be smaller than the former, but with bars of equal width (if this is possible). Thanks for letting me know about coord_cartesian though, I'll do some more playing about with it

Comment: @LIIVI ah, I see. I thought you wanted the space on either side of the bars to grow and shrink. You want the panel to grow and shrink, so that the bars are constant width, and the distance between the edge of the bars and the panel edge is also constant, meaning the panel itself grows and shrinks - is that correct?

Comment: Hi Allan, yes that's correct. When I manually adjust the size of the panel, the bar width changes inconsistently due to the gap between the bars and the axis. I would like to keep this gap as it is, but also keep the bars at a constant width. As an example, in the image I posted the bars are not the same width (though they look approximately the same), even though they should be the same based on the size of the panels. Hope that makes sense!